# Eclipse cannot find javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am using GWT with AppEngine on Eclipse.  When I try to build a simple Servlet, Eclipse keeps complaining that `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` " cannot be found in source packages ".

How can I get Eclipse happy?

**updated:** found the problem: it seems Eclipse with the GWT pluging would rather have server-side code in a `.server` package.

Comment: That's another good reason why it wouldn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the gwt-user.jar from the gwt sdk is on your build path.

Answer (score 0):

You could use maven and add a dependency toward a servlet-xxx jar like servlet-api-2.4.jar.